# python search for "\|" and replace with " "

Tags: python, regex, escaping

I'm getting data with the field delimiter "|"

```
field 1 | field 2 | field 3
```

are the regular line i get.

The exception looks like

```
field 1 | 2\|2\|2 | field 3
```

my python program should return

```
field 1 | 2 2 2 | field 3
```

I'm looking for the python 2.6 regular expression to replace the `\|` with a blank .
I've made many tries but have mainly replaced the regular field delimiter as well.
The latest try was

```
line = re.sub("\\\\\|", " ", line)
```

Comment: Just use string functions and replace `'\|'`. No need for regex here. See it in use [here](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/v1jBVkHJUKFGwSimBoSArLTM1JwUBWMlroKizLwShWK9otSCnMTkVA2lmBolHQUlBSXN//8B)

Comment: line.replace("\|", " ")

Comment: using line = re.sub(r"\|"," ",line) returned 
Field 1 2 2 2 Field 3
the regular field delimiter were removed as well.

Comment: using line.replace("\|", " ") removes the additional backslash but leave the addtional pipe symbol, where it it. instead of the expted 3 field I'm getting five. Like 
Field 1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | Field 3

Comment: @Leo65 to use `re.sub` you would need `re.sub(r"\\\|"," ", line)`, note, I'm *escaping* **both** the backslash to get an acual backslash, i.e. \\-> \ as well as the pipe, because the pipe is also an alternation operator in regex: `\|` -> `|`. However, what you **really** should use is simply `line.replace('\|',' ')` as others have pointed out

Comment: @Leo65 no, it does not. `line.replace('\|',' ')` gives me `'1 | 2 2 2 | field 3'`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga
thanks for your response as all the others. i agree line.replace would be the better function. Unfortunately within my python 2.6 environment it just removes the back slash and leave the additional pipe in the line.

Comment: @Leo65 it does not, I just tested it in Python 2.6 (which is 10 year old,by the way). Regardeless, I showed you a way it *would* work with `re.sub`, but I suspect that the problem is you aren't adequately reproducing your input. Since `line.replace` should work on all Python 2 or 3 versions in that way.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga sound promissing, I've to check my script how the assignment works when it's used a second time.

Comment: @Leo65 what do you mean?

Comment: That my starting point
 line = inputfilehandle.readline()
            if line:
                if line.count("|") == actual_field:
                   drline = line
else:
   line.replace('\|',' ')
if line.count("|") == actual_field:
The number of fields is still bigger than the expected numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
line.replace('\|',' ')
```

The string method **replace** will work here. If you can avoid using regex, you will save yourself a headache. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) for more information.

Comment: in my environment using python 2.6 only

line = re.sub(r"\\\|", " ", line)

worked for me. r three back slashed and one pipe symbol.

Thanks for the construtive feedbacks.